# Округление числа после запятой

Tags: javascript, jquery, округление

Пример число **117.6800000000001**

Нужно округлить в виде **117.7**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
var x = 117.6800000000001, y = 117;

console.log(x.toFixed(1), Math.round(x*10)/10);
console.log(y.toFixed(1), Math.round(y*10)/10);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. умножить на 10
2. `Math.round()`
3. разделить на 10